# How to know if bootstrap changed

Tags: boot, mbr

Worry if the virus changes grub2 in the first 446 bytes of disk where is grub2. If it get changed, how do i notice?

Comment: how to do and why?

Answer (score 1):

***Before*** you get infected, and assuming your disk is `/dev/sdq`,

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdq of=/tmp/sdq.mbr bs=466 count=1
```

Move `/tmp/sdq.mbr` onto a removable USB key. Remove it and keep it safe.

Then, to check, re-insert the USB key and

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdq of=/tmp/sdq.newmbr bs=466 count=1

cmp /tmp/sdq.newmbr /media/USB\ key/sdq.mbr
```

But, I must point out that you're probably solving the wrong problem. This isn't important.

Comment: Thank u telling me This isn't important, I don't know before, why This isn't important ?